# Json and wordpress and jquerymobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, web-applications

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ya Rab</title>
    <!--styles and scripts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Zahran-Flat-Theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" />
    <!--styles and scripts-->
    </head>
<body>
<!--page-->
<div id="blogpost" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
  <!--Header--><div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>ZahranPress</h1>
</div><!--Header-->
<div data-role="content" id="mypost">


</div><!--Content-->



<script src="http://testzahran.marocwebs.com/?json=recentstories&callback=ListPosts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ya Rab</title>
    <!--styles and scripts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Zahran-Flat-Theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" />
    <!--styles and scripts-->
    </head>
<body>
<!--page-->
<div id="blogpost" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
  <!--Header--><div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>ZahranPress</h1>
</div><!--Header-->
<div data-role="content" id="mypost">


</div><!--Content-->



<script src="http://testzahran.marocwebs.com/?json=recentstories&callback=ListPosts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi 
I was trying to develop wordpress app using jquery and json for this site [ZahranPress](http://testzahran.marocwebs.com) and it didn't work and I checked it many times. I coded it according to this cool tutorial [Jquery mobile app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUpWq9_LeEo&list=PLpyMIOJ_U4sxgKMNMIyPqMjISaTaL4hU2&index=23) Here's the html code and javascript. hope anybody help.

Comment: What do you think does not work? What is the expected behavior? Is the HTML the same in first and second listing?

Comment: well It has to view the title of the post in h3 and the featured image of the post and the post itself and I think the error in js @MaxZoom